# elasticsearch - how to add new shards and split index content

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

So I my index growth too fast and now has 60 million docs in 3 shards (single node).

I want to buy more machines and split content into more shards. How can I do this?

It's just connect new nodes to the cluster and update shards number in master?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik elasticsearch cannot yet redistribute indexed documents automatically ([see here](http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com/)). You would have to reindex all content. The problem behind it is, that documents are distributed to shards according to a hash value modulo number of shards. Just adding shards and keeping indexing would keep adding documents to the old shards too.

Elasticsearch allows to distribute documents according to a custom function (routing parameter). You could distribute all new content to the new shards, but this makes deletions difficult, because now you have to know if a document is "old" or "new". Further it ruins your uniform index statistics which may bias ranking in nonobvious ways.

Bottom line: adding shards to an existing index requires reindexing all contents or some heavy hacking.

Answer (score 1):

You already have 3 shards, so if you add 2 nodes Elasticsearch will automatically reallocate 2 shards to the other 2 nodes, giving all shard 3 times more power.

If you want to add more shards, you need to reindex your data. This can be done by creating a new index with the desired number of shards and copying your data to that index (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html)